# Entity Framework 6 - StoreGeneratedPattern value not staying

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, ado.net

We are using Entity Framework 6.2.0 against an Oracle 12c database, and have been following the Database-First approach.

A lot of our tables have an `_ID` column that is generated by the database upon INSERT. This is done by using a default value on the DB server, `TABLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL`.

After generating the DB model in Entity Framework, I went through and marked each `_ID` column as `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` and we were all set to go. However, when updating the DB model after some DB changes, we noticed an issue. One table in particular forgets this setting and resets this back to `None`. All other tables remember `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"`.

This consistently happens each time we update the DB model from the database. 
Visual Studio will still say that `PROBLEMATIC_TABLE_ID` has `Identity` set, but the .edmx file does not.
My process has been to update the model, then open the .edmx file and manually paste in `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` for that one column.

I have compared this table against others in the DB, in the .edmx, in the codebase, and I cannot find anything that would cause this one column on this one table to behave differently upon DB model update.

TL;DR: Upon updating our local DB model from the database, the value for `StoreGeneratedPattern` on *one* column/table is always reset, while all others stay the same. VS still says it is `Identity`, but the XML in the .edmx file disagrees and needs to be updated manually.

Comment: `One table in particular forgets this setting and resets this back to None` Please post its definition. Does it use specific feature like table partitioning/physical file location/clustering?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda The table in the EDMX file looks like this: https://gist.github.com/neilsimp1/f43fb2f3e8fca8f7f9b8b1e013fc25ca. Nothing special, it is set up the same as every other table we are using.

Comment: Do other tables also have XMLTYPE/CLOB columns?

Comment: Several other tables have CLOBs, but this is the only table with XMLTYPE.

Comment: I would grab the SQL code that is generated during migration, I guess that the table is rebuilded every time and `DEFAULT TABLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL` is lost

Comment: We're doing Database-First, so there are no migrations. If something in the DB schema is updated, we update our model from the DB schema. It doesn't matter if this table is changed or not during that process, this one column *always* loses the `StoreGeneratedPattern` in the XML.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by *"VS still says it is `Identity`*"? By VS do you mean EDMX designer properties, data annotation on the generated code or something else?

Comment: Sure. After Updating the Model from the DB, if I go in VS Model Designer to the Properties for the column in question, it will still say that `StoreGeneratedPattern` is Identity. However the .edmx file doesn't gave `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` in it and I have to re-add that manually each time.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what's the problem w/o repro. The edmx should contain 2 `EntityType` definitions. I can see the one from `edmx:StorageModels` in the `table.xml` link from your comments, could you provide a similar for the corresponding definition from `edmx:ConceptualModels`?

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Does it occur if you create an EDMX for this table only? If not, add another table, etc. Also, if you restart VS and reopen the EDMX, does it still show identity in the EDMX designer? If so, I wonder where it gets this info from.